# PHP: Returning string from server to client when json_encode fails

Tags: php, json

I'm writing an application that sends some data to my server in order to produce a PDF file. To do this I use shell_exec to call on the approapiate latex compilation command. I always show the output of log in the cliente by using the following code in the server(this is oversimpliefied to show the problem):

```
$log = shell_exec("cd ../../template; pdflatex $texinput;");
$ret["log"] = $log;
echo json_encode($ret);
```

However every once in a while the log will contain a chararcter that will break the json_encode. That is json_enconde($ret) will be false.

Is there any other way to send the information (as text or maybe as a file) to the client?

EDIT: 
Since the output is the output of a Latex compilation it is very difficult to reproduce simply. However, as I've been asked to provide an example, I managed to create this minimal example using the log file (automatically saved by the pdflatex command) and this minimal php script.

This is the PHP script:

```
  $trial = "trial.log";
  $handle = fopen($trial,"r");  
  $data = fread($handle,filesize($trial));
  if ($handle === false){
      $errors = error_get_last();     
      $ret["error"] = "Could not open $trial for reading. Type: " . $errors["type"] . " MSG: " . $errors["message"];
      return;
  }
  fclose($handle);

  echo "Done reading<br>";

  if (json_encode($data) === false){
    echo "I've failed";
  }
  else{
    echo "All good";
  }
```

This is the file trial.log

https://www.dropbox.com/s/04ejx5s1mj0ojj2/trial.log?dl=0

I've tested it in my browser and I get the I've failed. However I have bypassed the problem. (See my answer)

Comment: What happens when `$textinput` is `; rm -rf /*`?

Comment: I don't undersand. For one, It can never be that as I create the value of $texinput programatically from values that are not user dependant. Two, what does that have to do with my question?

Comment: If you assign the value and it is in no way effected by the data sent to the server.

Comment: I have never had `json_encode` fail to encode an array except if it contained complicated objects. So I am very interested to know what exactly might be in `$log` that makes it fail... is it *huge*? does it contain binary data? 4-byte utf8 (smileys for example)? Can you provoke the error with something like this and post result `if(!json_encode($ret)) file_put_contents('fail.log', var_export($log,true));`

Comment: Oh - also we'll need to know how you are picking this up in the client to answer your question - when you `echo` back `json_encode` you actually *are* sending just plain text - it's the receiving end that picks up this plain text and then interprets it as something "special" (ie. an array)... which is probably entirely unnecessary for your purposes (but should be fully possible nevertheless)

Comment: Need some information on what `$ret['log']` contains when failure is encountered otherwise this is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a couple of different things, I went with trying to send the pdflatex generated log file to the client. So instead of returning the contents of the file (which are the same as the contents returned by the command) y returned the path to the log file. Then in my browser I used this code:

```
        // Getting the base URL 
        var url = window.location.href;
        var l = url.length;
        while (l--){
          if (url[l] == '/') break;
        }
        url = url.substring(0,l);

        // Creating the URL for the log file.
        var logfile = url + obj.logfile;
```

The obj.logfile was the relative path in my server to the log file. Then I used the following to load the file into a text area.

```
// Loading the log file.
$.ajax({
  type:    "GET",
  url:     logfile,
  success: function(text) {
     document.getElementById("pdflatex_out").value = text;
  },
  error:   function() {
     document.getElementById("pdflatex_out").value = "Error. please contact the administrator";
  }
  });
```